# What data type do I use for a MYSQL column to connect it to a Java List<String>?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I'm using Spring, MVC design pattern. Spring Data JPA.

More specifically connect the MYSQL column to a List in my Java Model class. What data type do I use for that in MYSQL?

I'm trying to do this for the purpose of creating custom columns for a table on the the front end UI. Idea being that I can use the List so custom column names (and data populated in this custom column) will appear on the front end UI table, but on the back end in MYSQL, it is actually under one pre-made column I created in MYSQL. Thanks!

Comment: It is customary to use a separate table with columns (fk, value); note that Set is much more efficient than List if order is not required.

Comment: You don't. You normalize the data. Part of that consists of removing array columns.

Comment: @user207421 Uh oh. "Normalizing the data" is a new term to me. What exactly is this? I think I read a little bit about this. Something to do with using XML or JSON in the process? Or is there another way?

Comment: It is a fundamental principle of SQL that is too broad to explain here. Look up '3rd normal form'. Nothing to do with XML or JSON whatsoever. They weren't invented by several decades when 3NF was formulated.

Comment: I would thought you obtained a java.sql.ResultSet and iterated it to collect the information but if checking each "data type" for a column then theresultset.getMetaData() java.sql.ResultSetMetaData and theresultset.getObject(int columnIndex, Class<T> type) would be useful in the iteration.